# Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на меню остальная область затемнялась?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как сделать затемнение всего окна сайта, когда наводишь курсор на меню?

Comment: Я так понял с помощью hover и jquery ?

Comment: @Pashok какой же это дубликат. там внутри элемента затеняется, а  тут надо наоброт все внешнее затенить.

Comment: А каким образом все окно кроме меню на которое навел затемнить ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись в данном случае без JavaScript и использовать `box-shadow` с "бесконечной тенью" (длиной `100vmax`). Так как IE не распознаёт единицы `vmax` ему даётся fallback (запасной вариант) c огромной величиной `99999px` вместо `100vmax`. При необходимости для самого меню на псевдокласс `:hover` можно добавить также `background-color` того же цвета, что и затемнение. Демонстрация:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav__item {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.nav:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); /* fallback for IE */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item">пункт 1</li>
  <li class="nav__item">пункт 2</li>
  <li class="nav__item">пункт 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
var colorHover = "rgba(0,0,0, .5)";
var colorUnHover = "#fff";

var items  = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__item");

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onmouseover = function() {
    wrap.style.background = colorHover;
  }

  item.onmouseleave = function() {
    wrap.style.background = colorUnHover;
  }
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: .5s;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav__item {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav__item">пункт 1</li>
    <li class="nav__item">пункт 2</li>
    <li class="nav__item">пункт 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Уверен ваш ответ будет правильным )) Сейчас проверим!

Comment: а само меню цвет менять не будет ?? Мне нужно что бы только внешнее окошко затемнялось!

Comment: нет, не будет)) фон меняется у внешнего блока, фон пунктов навигации при этом не меняется, попробуйте еще раз, так будет наглядней

Comment: Отлично, то что мне нужно!! Спасибо за труд , оценил !))

Comment: пожалуйста)))))

Comment: Почему затемняется только область дива в котором я разместил меню? как сделать затемнение на все окно ??

Comment: @CoffeeKyiv Сделал более универсальное решение без использования JavaScript.